# Pandas Knowing the Employee of a Boss

Tags: pandas, recursion

Is it possible to extract the hierarchy of employee by a given table using pandas?

for example we have this table

```
+-------+--------+
| empID | bossID |
+-------+--------+
| a1    | b2     |
| a2    | a1     |
| c1    | a2     |
| d2    | a2     |
| a4    | aa     |
+-------+--------+
```

employee b2 on bossID Column has an employee a1 on empID column. and a1 on BossID has an employee e1,

so the expected result would be `[b2,a1,a2,c1,d2]`

currently, I can retrieve only 1 layer.

```
details = df[('bossID') == "b2"]
details = df['empID'].tolist()
details = list(set(details))
print(details) # ['b2','a1']
```

but going deeper proves to be difficult. I tried putting it on a function and tried recursion but it does not succeed.

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)  (DAG) problem. You might consider using [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is look like a network problem , so we using `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'empID', 'bossID')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
l
Out[184]: [{'a1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c1', 'd2'}, {'a4', 'aa'}]
```

Comment: interesting, will accept as answer when proven. thank you very much